# Session timeout is not sliding in Azure Redis Cache Session State Provider

Tags: azure, redis, session-timeout, azure-redis-cache

Scaling out web application through multiple instances is one of biggest advantages of azure cloud. To achieve multiple VMs support for our web-role cloud application we are implementing Azure Redis Cache. We are using RedisSessionStateProvider provider for maintaining session state. Following are the configuration settings for session management within web.config file.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="20" defaultUrl="~/Default" />
</authentication>
<sessionState timeout="20" mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
  <providers>
     <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider"
        host = "dummy.redis.cache.windows.net" 
        port = "6380" 
        accessKey = "dummysecretkey" 
        ssl = "true" 
        throwOnError = "true" 
        retryTimeoutInMilliseconds = "5000" 
        databaseId = "0" 
        applicationName = "" 
        connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds = "5000" 
        operationTimeoutInMilliseconds = "1000" 
        connectionString = ""/>  
  </providers>
```

Our problem is that session timeout is not extending with the user's postback, suppose our user logs into the application at 10:00 AM then his session data will expire at absolute 10:20 AM. If user postbacks at 10:15 AM then session should expire at 10:35 AM but this is not happening it is expiring on 10:20 AM absolute.

Following is the code at login button's click event

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(TextBox1.Text.Trim(), true);
   ConnectionMultiplexer connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connec("dummy.redis.cache.windows.net,ssl=true,password=dummysecretkey");
   IDatabase cache = connection.GetDatabase();
   Session["UserName"] = TextBox1.Text;
   Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
 }
```

I would appreciate if could let me know what needs to be done to get session timeout in sliding mode.
Best Regards,

H.R Yadav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks you for reporting the issue. We have released a new version of RedisSessionStateProvider NuGet package that fixes above reported bug.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider/1.5.0

EDIT:
We have found one more issue with this. ASP.NET doesn't call ResetItemTimeout for AJAX requests and it becomes responsibility of other session state method to slide the session timeout. We have fixed this bug and released a new NuGet package:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider/1.6.5

Let us know is this resolves your issue or not?

Comment: Thanks very much guys for releasing the new version. Now I have no problem with session timeout. Each postback is extending session timeout as desired. I am wondering how you guys missed this bug since it will be very common issue for all who maintain session state in redis cache?

Comment: It didn't existed earlier. It was regression from another fix. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: This issue still exists. I'm using 1.6.3

Comment: @MaDeRkAn: Can you please provide the way you are configuring and using session state? This issue should not happen with latest nuget package.

Comment: ssl=true,throwOnError=true,retryTimeoutInMilliseconds=0,connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds=5000,operationTimeoutInMilliseconds=5000. It's just sliding, if I add/change in session.

Comment: @MaDeRkAn: Use logging mechanism available with latest session state provider 1.6.4. Check that ResetItemTimeout is getting called during every request.

Comment: @Siddharth Chatrola: I'm on 1.6.4, with default settings and my session is also behaving strange. Sometimes the expiry timeout gets refreshed and sometimes not, doing the same operation. Also, once the session is expired (ttl command on redis returns -2) it sometimes still works and the session gets revived. So far I have noticed this strange behavior when using HttpHandlers (*.ashx) using IRequiresSessionState. When using ASPX pages, it seems to be OK.

Comment: Hey all - this (the comment section under an answer) isn't the place to be discussing bugs and holding Q&A.

Comment: I have Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider 2.2.0 then also i am getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem of sliding expiration including the following lines in global.ascx.cs

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
    {
        RedisSessionStateProvider redis = new RedisSessionStateProvider();
        redis.ResetItemTimeout(HttpContext.Current, HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the way you are configuring and using session state? This issue should not happen with latest nuget package.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. ASP.NET doesn't call ResetItemTimeout for AJAX requests and it becomes responsibility of other session state method to slide the session timeout. We have fixed this bug and released a new NuGet package:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider/1.6.5

Let us know is this resolves your issue or not?

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset the key yourself (after you load it):

```
bool KeyExpire(RedisKey key, DateTime? expiry, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None);
bool KeyExpire(RedisKey key, TimeSpan? expiry, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None);
```

Comment: Do we need to reset key on every fetch operation performed on session variable? If this the case the how we will manage expiry of application level variables that are shared by all users and session level variables that are specific to only user?

Comment: I don`t user sessionState at all. But AFAIK you have to reset the key on every fetch operation to get a "sliding" caching mechanism since redis doesn't provide it yet.

Comment: Then how would you manage user's session data and application level variables?

Comment: depends on your needs. If you need application level variables to be persistent, you can use Table Storage or Azure SQL. Maybe take a look at the msdn design patterns guid for Azure: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600223.aspx

Comment: If we set value to any new or existing session variable then session timeout is sliding but if we only fetch session variables then session is timedout at absolute time.

Please suggest what may be the issue.

Comment: You have to set call keyExpire after eatch fetch: database.StringGet() and then database.KeyExpire()

Comment: You should not do this from application. Session state should do this. If it is not doing it then please provide your configuration and we can find and fix bug if one exists.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. ASP.NET doesn't call ResetItemTimeout for AJAX requests and it becomes responsibility of other session state method to slide the session timeout. We have fixed this bug and released a new NuGet package:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider/1.6.5

Let us know is this resolves your issue or not?