# Session timeout is not sliding in Azure Redis Cache Session State Provider Additional

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, azure, caching, redis

As instructed, I am creating a new question instead of adding information to the identical article: 
[Session timeout is not sliding in Azure Redis Cache Session State Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292265/session-timeout-is-not-sliding-in-azure-redis-cache-session-state-provider)

I also have this issue, and feel I have additional information to contribute.  I was unable to add a comment (it said I do not have enough reputation), so I tried to post a response and it was deleted because it was not an answer and was instructed to ask a new question, so here it is.

I saw on the other post, Siddharth Chatrola asked for people who had this issue to provide their configuration and logging information.

Note that our application is an Asp.Net Mvc 'Single Page Application', so we use ajax to request content to load into a div, I am wondering if this is the reason that ResetItemTimeout is not being reliably called.

This failure of the cache is causing our uses to be logged out. We have set a 200 minute timeout and that has helped, but we really need this to work correctly. The value in using the Azure Cloud Service architecture is that it is scalable, but if you cannot reliably maintain session when you have more than one instance, the value is lost.

I am using version 1.6.4. 
Here is our configuration:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore" timeout="200">
  <providers>


    <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider"
         host="focuscache.redis.cache.windows.net"
         accessKey="xxxx"
         port="6380"
         ssl="true"
         applicationName="Esurety"
         loggingClassName = "Esurety.Core.Utility.StringUtilities, Esurety.Core, Version=6.0.9.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
         loggingMethodName = "GetLogger"
         />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

I have enabled logging, and I can see that ResetItemTimeout is not getting called most of the time:

```
[2015-07-30 16:00:04.591][Info]GetItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602.
[2015-07-30 16:00:04.622][Info]GetItemFromSessionStore => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => Lock taken with lockId: 635738688045914548
[2015-07-30 16:00:04.947][Info]ReleaseItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => For lockId: 635738688045914548.
[2015-07-30 16:00:05.094][Info]GetItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602.
[2015-07-30 16:00:05.116][Info]GetItemFromSessionStore => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => Lock taken with lockId: 635738688050941381
[2015-07-30 16:00:05.698][Info]ReleaseItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => For lockId: 635738688050941381.
[2015-07-30 16:00:10.301][Info]GetItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602.
[2015-07-30 16:00:10.316][Info]GetItemFromSessionStore => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => Lock taken with lockId: 635738688103013334
[2015-07-30 16:00:10.619][Info]ReleaseItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => For lockId: 635738688103013334.
[2015-07-30 16:00:10.796][Info]GetItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602.
[2015-07-30 16:00:10.820][Info]GetItemFromSessionStore => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => Lock taken with lockId: 635738688107968188
[2015-07-30 16:00:11.992][Info]ReleaseItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => For lockId: 635738688107968188.
[2015-07-30 16:03:29.088][Info]GetItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602.
[2015-07-30 16:03:29.119][Info]GetItemFromSessionStore => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => Lock taken with lockId: 635738690090883595
[2015-07-30 16:03:37.776][Info]ReleaseItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => For lockId: 635738690090883595.
[2015-07-30 16:06:15.967][Info]GetItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602.
[2015-07-30 16:06:15.983][Info]GetItemFromSessionStore => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => Lock taken with lockId: 635738691759679369
[2015-07-30 16:06:16.935][Info]ReleaseItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => For lockId: 635738691759679369.
[2015-07-30 16:06:23.869][Info]GetItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602.
[2015-07-30 16:06:23.895][Info]GetItemFromSessionStore => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => Lock taken with lockId: 635738691838698966
[2015-07-30 16:06:24.130][Info]ReleaseItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => For lockId: 635738691838698966.
[2015-07-30 16:06:24.319][Info]GetItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602.
[2015-07-30 16:06:24.351][Info]GetItemFromSessionStore => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => Lock taken with lockId: 635738691843199332
[2015-07-30 16:06:24.703][Info]ReleaseItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => For lockId: 635738691843199332.
[2015-07-30 16:06:26.951][Info]GetItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602.
[2015-07-30 16:06:26.962][Info]GetItemFromSessionStore => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => Lock taken with lockId: 635738691869519009
[2015-07-30 16:06:27.408][Info]ReleaseItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => For lockId: 635738691869519009.
[2015-07-30 16:06:27.561][Info]GetItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602.
[2015-07-30 16:06:27.576][Info]GetItemFromSessionStore => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => Lock taken with lockId: 635738691875611489
[2015-07-30 16:06:28.121][Info]ReleaseItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => For lockId: 635738691875611489.
[2015-07-30 16:06:31.225][Info]GetItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602.
[2015-07-30 16:06:31.256][Info]GetItemFromSessionStore => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => Lock taken with lockId: 635738691912250593
[2015-07-30 16:06:31.632][Info]ReleaseItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => For lockId: 635738691912250593.
[2015-07-30 16:06:31.821][Info]GetItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602.
[2015-07-30 16:06:31.838][Info]GetItemFromSessionStore => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => Lock taken with lockId: 635738691918218208
[2015-07-30 16:06:32.294][Info]ReleaseItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => For lockId: 635738691918218208.
[2015-07-30 16:06:34.764][Info]GetItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602.
[2015-07-30 16:06:34.779][Info]GetItemFromSessionStore => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => Lock taken with lockId: 635738691947640393
[2015-07-30 16:06:35.296][Info]ReleaseItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => For lockId: 635738691947640393.
[2015-07-30 16:07:57.461][Info]GetItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602.
[2015-07-30 16:07:57.493][Info]GetItemFromSessionStore => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => Lock taken with lockId: 635738692774614613
[2015-07-30 16:07:58.103][Info]ReleaseItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => For lockId: 635738692774614613.
[2015-07-30 16:08:08.723][Info]GetItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602.
[2015-07-30 16:08:08.754][Info]GetItemFromSessionStore => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => Lock taken with lockId: 635738692887232898
[2015-07-30 16:08:15.001][Info]ReleaseItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => For lockId: 635738692887232898.
[2015-07-30 16:08:21.752][Info]GetItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602.
[2015-07-30 16:08:21.767][Info]GetItemFromSessionStore => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => Lock taken with lockId: 635738693017522310
[2015-07-30 16:08:22.035][Info]ReleaseItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => For lockId: 635738693017522310.
[2015-07-30 16:08:25.652][Info]GetItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602.
[2015-07-30 16:08:25.683][Info]GetItemFromSessionStore => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => Lock taken with lockId: 635738693056520881
[2015-07-30 16:08:27.330][Info]ReleaseItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => For lockId: 635738693056520881.
[2015-07-30 16:08:27.535][Info]GetItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602.
[2015-07-30 16:08:27.550][Info]GetItemFromSessionStore => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => Lock taken with lockId: 635738693075350154
[2015-07-30 16:08:28.555][Info]ReleaseItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => For lockId: 635738693075350154.
[2015-07-30 16:08:53.456][Info]GetItemExclusive => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602.
[2015-07-30 16:08:53.472][Info]GetItemFromSessionStore => Session Id: xw5nbfaiktejo5rinhbdrvjm, Session provider object: 49331602 => Lock taken with lockId: 635738693334565328
```

If anyone can provide a way to trigger ResetItemTimeout on an Asp.Net MVC SPA, i would appreciate the help.  I have sublcassed Controller class so I can easily add something to OnActionExecuting or OnActionExecuted that could reset the timer.

Thank you very much for any help,
Danny Green

Comment: Hello, if anyone can help, I also have a small sample project that clearly demonstrates this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this issue. ASP.NET doesn't call ResetItemTimeout for AJAX requests and it becomes responsibility of other session state method to slide the session timeout. We have fixed this bug and released a new NuGet package:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider/1.6.5

Let us know is this resolves your issue or not?